# How to deploy appfuse on cloudfoundry or elsewhere?

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo, cloud-foundry, appfuse

I would like to deploy appfuse into cloudfoundry. When I run these unix commands:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-spring-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.1 -DgroupId=se.ova -DartifactId=artpage -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse
cd artpage
mvn clean install -Ppostgresql
vmc push
more ~/.vmc/crash
```

I get this message:

```
Time of crash:
  2013-02-12 11:24:26 +0100

CFoundry::AppInvalid: 300: Invalid application description

cfoundry-0.4.21/lib/cfoundry/v1/base.rb:113:in `handle_response'
cfoundry-0.4.21/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:146:in `block in request_uri'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
cfoundry-0.4.21/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:127:in `request_uri'
cfoundry-0.4.21/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:48:in `request'
cfoundry-0.4.21/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:44:in `request_path'
cfoundry-0.4.21/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:193:in `request_with_options'
cfoundry-0.4.21/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:205:in `post'
cfoundry-0.4.21/lib/cfoundry/v1/model_magic.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in define_client_methods'
cfoundry-0.4.21/lib/cfoundry/v1/model.rb:72:in `create!'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push/create.rb:59:in `block in create_app'
interact-0.5.2/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push/create.rb:58:in `create_app'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:95:in `setup_new_app'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:82:in `push'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `run'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in `block in invoke'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:113:in `call'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Manifests>'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/callbacks.rb:74:in `with_filters'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:112:in `block in <class:Manifests>'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:50:in `execute'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:106:in `execute'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership.rb:45:in `start'
vmc-0.4.7/bin/vmc:11:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/vmc:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/vmc:23:in `<main>'
```

Does anybody has an idea what is wrong or how I can deploy appfuse on some other PaaS?
I have deployed roo applications to cloudfoundry and it works great, but I have diffculties to further develop roo apps and for example adding image upload and email configuration so I thought appfuse would be easier, but I like to deploy it somehow to a PaaS service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vmc push` assumes that you want to deploy from the current directory. This fails in your example because what is there is not a deliverables app, but the sources for it.

Either

- go to the `target/<the_exploded_app>` directory and do `vmc push`
- or use `vmc push --path target/<the_exploded_app_or_the_dot_war>`

that should do it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I keep that in mind, but I still get the same stack trace when I do:`vmc push --path target/artpage-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` To the vmc questions I answer: my email, 1 instances, spring and java7, 512 M. I will try with a simpler app. I don't really understand the service binding part, but I guess I should read more...

Comment: Strange indeed. FYI, service binding concerns provisioning some kind of persistence (eg. MySQL or postgresql I guess in your case) and making your deployed app aware of it. In turn, your app can either explicitly connect to it (tedious) or automagically (depending of your app framework. Spring, Node and RoR support it). Should work with appfuse.

Comment: So where do I enter the dbms credentials if I choose the automagical solution?

Comment: You don't. That's the point. At staging time, your sole bean of type DataSource will get replaced by one that knows how to connect to the db. More info here: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html

Comment: It works a bit better now. The stack trace was because I forgot the app name. It should be `vmc push <worldwide unique appname> --path target/<the_exploded_app_or_the_dot_war>` so the application starts now. Then I have bound a service and saved it, but when it is checking (means running the tests?) it fails, maybe because some tests try to use SMTP.

Comment: Still problem though: When I do `vmc start artpage` it says Starting artpage... OK, Checking artpage... GAVE UP. This happens also when I try to deploy appfuse light that I don't think use smtp. When I do `vmc logs artpage`it shows a stack trace to long to post here including this information: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException

Comment: The file applicationContext-dao.xml does not seem to exist in appfuse, although it is refered to in the context-param section of web.xml. Maybe this is an appfuse problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the root cause, which is far down the stack, you would see an error saying,

**Unable to create index directory: /nonexistent/artpage-1.0-SNAPSHOT/index for index org.appfuse.model.User**

This means that there is no write permission as the indexing was being creating on the disk.
Here is a nice blog which should help you out on your issue:

http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/Preparing-for-the-2-2-Release-td4655656.html

Also remember that, the files created will only last as long as the app instance is running.